# How to access CFQUERY SUM value

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion, cfquery

I am trying to get a single numeric value from a `<cfquery>` that is performing a SUMPRODUCT calc.  I know that the the following code works to produce the desired value (verified through `<cfdump>`).  I just need to know how to get that value as something that I can further manipulate in a `<cfset>` and display in a `<cfoutput>`.

This is the code that I am using:

```
<cfquery datasource="db" name="mQry">
    SELECT 
        SUM(factors.wt * temp.dp) 
    FROM
        factors
            INNER JOIN
        temp ON factors.fpID = temp.fpID
    WHERE
        factors.fpID IS NOT NULL
        AND temp.fpID IS NOT NULL  
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#mQry#">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you need to name the column in your query using [`AS ColumnAlias`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL))

```
<cfquery datasource="db" name="mQry">
SELECT 
    SUM(factors.wt * temp.dp) AS SumProduct
FROM
    factors
        INNER JOIN
    temp ON factors.fpID = temp.fpID
WHERE
    factors.fpID IS NOT NULL
    AND temp.fpID IS NOT NULL  
</cfquery>
```

To set it to a variable:

```
<cfset myVariable = mQry.sumProduct>
```

To output it

```
<cfoutput>#mQry.sumProduct#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Yep.  "AS" is what was missing.  Thx